# some problems related to primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

I would like to learn the following:

a) Prove that the equation $1 + x + x^2 = py$ has integer solutions for inﬁnitely many primes $p$.

b)  Twin primes are those difference by 2. Show that 5 is the only prime belonging to two such pairs. Show also that there is a one-to-one correspondence between twin primes and positive integers n such that $d(n^2-1) = 4$, where as above $d(k)$ stands for the number of divisors of $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) The proof is a modification of the "Euclid" proof that there are infinitely many primes.  Let $p_1=3$. Putting $x=1$ and $y=1$, we see that $1+x+x^2=py$ has a solution.

Now suppose that we have found $n$ primes $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$ such that $1+x+x^2=p_iy$ has a solution for any $i$ from $1$ to $n$. We exhibit a new prime $p_{n+1}$ such that $1+x+x^2=p_{n+1}y$ has a solution.

Consider the number $1+(p_1p_2\cdots p_n)+(p_1p_2\cdots p_n)^2$. This is an integer $\gt 1$, so has a prime divisor $p_{n+1}$. Any such $p_{n+1}$ must be distinct from $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$. This is because if $p_{n+1}=p_i$, where $1\le i\le n$, then $p_i$ divides $(p_1p_2\cdots p_n)+(p_1p_2\cdots p_n)^2$, so cannot divide $1+ (p_1p_2\cdots p_n)+(p_1p_2\cdots p_n)^2$.

Thus we have found a new prime $p_{n+1}$ such that $1+x+x^2=p_{n+1}y$ has a solution.

b) The number $5$ belongs to the pairs $(3,5)$ and $(5,7)$. It is clear that $2$ does not belong to any pair, and $3$ belongs to only $1$ pair. We show that any prime $p\ge 7$ cannot belong to more than one pair. Suppose to the contrary that $p$ does. Then $p-2$, $p$, and $p+2$ are prime. Note that if $x$ is any integer, then one of $x-2$, $x$, or $x+2$ is divisible by $3$. A number divisible by $3$ and greater than $3$ cannot be prime.

For the second part of the question, we ask when $d(n^2-1)=4$. If $n$ is even, then $n-1$ and $n+1$ are relatively prime, so $d((n-1)(n+1))=d(n-1)d(n+1)$. But $1$ is the only $k$ such that $d(k)=1$. So we must have $d(n-1)=d(n+1)=2$. That forces the pair $(n-1,n+1)$ to be a pair of twin primes.

Now examine the case $n$ odd. Then $(n-1)(n+1)$ is divisible by $8$, so has the divisors $1$, $2$, $4$ and $8$. Since $d(n^2-1)=4$, it can have no others. Thus $n^2-1=8$, giving $n=3$.

So the set $A$ of numbers $n-1$ such that $d(n^2-1)=4$ consist of $2$ plus the smaller primes in a twin prime pair. This set can be easily put in one to one correspondence with the set $B$ of smaller primes in twin prime pairs. Just list the two sets as $a_1,a_2,\dots$ and $b_1,b_2,\dots$ and map $a_i$ to $b_i$.

But the one-to-one correspondence bit  has absolutely **nothing** to do with twin primes. For **any** two infinite sets of natural numbers can be put in one to one correspondence.  So to prove there is a one to one correspondence, we need not have done *any* analysis of the $n$ such that $d(n^2-1)=4$.

Comment: Nicolas! Excellent analysis you have given. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph... You are relying on the Twin Prime Conjecture, which is not known. We still need the analysis on n because it is not known whether either of these sets are finite or infinite.